# How many different endings does Sholay have?

Tags: ending, sholay

How many different endings does the movie [Sholay](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073707/) have?

I know of one in the ending of which [Thakur](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0023505) uses a shoe containing nails to destroy [Gabbar](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0027556/?ref_=tt_cl_t6)'s hand. There is definitely a second one which I have seen but can't recall. But I guess there are three.

[Wikipedia: Alternative version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sholay#Alternate_version)

Comment: After so much search, i don't think there is any more version available rather then your own mentioned.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I guess I have even seen a third version as well, but am in doubt. I am inclined towards three.

Comment: I didn't even know about the second till you asked this question, So it might be. Lets see.

Comment: The version where Gabbar gets killed (impaled) is available on YouTube. This was not passed by Censor board hence the one we all saw in the movie

Answer (score 3):

An old timer (*who was present at a private screening*) once told me that in the "**original**" ending of the movie, *Gabbar* (Amjad Khan) rolls off the boulders and lands on iron rod(s) when kicked by *Thakur* (Sanjeev Kumar). He is impaled on them or is seriously injured, leading to his death.

However, this ending was considered too soft and didn't exactly give a meaningful conclusion to what was supposed to be a ***revenge saga***. Moreover, the producers thought that this ending will not stir the emotions of the audience as the ending was too, well *chancey*!

This led to *Ramesh Sippy* shooting the next version in which *Thakur* kills *Gabbar*. And then there is the [censored alternate version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sholay#Alternate_version), mentioned in Wikipedia.

Hence,
**Total count of different endings = 3**

Comment: Where did you got to know this.

Comment: Question is where can one find the two uncommon endings.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: The answer to your question is in the very first few words of my answer.

Comment: @BleedingFingers: I am sorry but I thought this post was about finding the number and different endings for the movie. Please do correct me if I am wrong! Nevertheless, this is something based purely on hearsay and I personally don't hold a cut of the mentioned _original version_.

Comment: No, you got me wrong. You answered the question appropriately. That in the comment above was a different question.

Comment: As the censored alternate version is now available on YouTube, I think that the first and third endings you mention refer to the same version. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oh_WeoKJkUY

Answer (score 0):

I have seen 3 different ending

1. Main stream: Thakur about to crush Gabbar's face and police comes by. Thakur stops and Gabbar is arrested.
2. Thakur  crushes Gabbar's face with his shoes. This version has additional scenes showing Ramlal fitting spikes to Thakur's shoes.

3.Thakur kicks Gabbar and Gabbar dies as the metal pierces his heart from his back.

There is true meaning to "Gabbar tere liye to mere pair hi kaafi hai"

Answer (score -1):

It has just two endings.

1. Where they show gabbar dying
2. Where they didn't show gabbar dying.

There aren't any other endings.

Comment: Doesn't adds any additional value to the existing answer.

Answer (score -1):

I watched two types of endings-

1. In India on TVs and movie theatre screens Gabbar arrested by police.
2. In USA, on Netflix dvd I watched Gabbar killed by Thakur.

Comment: Can  you add source to this